# Flutter error at running in pyshical device

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am getting this error un multiples projects, looks like gradle or a service is down i dont kwon what is happening, it could be a new update in the gradle or the android sdk if someone can tell me how to run properly i will appreciate

my flutter version is

```bash
Flutter 3.10.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f468f3366c (11 days ago) • 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
Engine • revision cdbeda788a
Tools • Dart 3.0.6 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  firebase_core: ^2.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^4.1.0
  provider: ^6.0.4
  flutter_secure_storage: ^8.0.0
  dio: ^5.3.0
  dartz: ^0.10.1
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
```

this is the error when running debug mode in vscode

```json
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.16.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2 > org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2
      > Could not resolve com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.16.
         > Could not parse POM https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/FastInfoset/1.2.16/FastInfoset-1.2.16.pom
            > Could not find fastinfosat-project-1.2.16.pom (com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:fastinfosat-project:1.2.16).
              Searched in the following locations:
                  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/fastinfosat-project/1.2.16/fastinfosat-project-1.2.16.pom
```

this is my settings.gradle file

```
include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
```

this is my build.gradle in android folder

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my adroind/app/build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.diferenteweb.spotcafe"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The dependency `com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.16` wasn't found on maven, hence your gradle sync failed.

I can see the POM file at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/fastinfoset-project/1.2.16/fastinfoset-project-1.2.16.pom.

```
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/fastinfoset/fastinfosat-project/1.2.16/fastinfosat-project-1.2.16.pom
```

This line has a typo in the name in your error log.

I'm not exactly sure what plugin might be using this, can you try updating the `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'`?

Comment: how i add this dependency ?

Comment: do you have something like mavenCentral in your android/build.gradle file? @LuisMonsalve

Comment: Yes i have i already update my question with all the information

Comment: Updated my answer, please try once

Comment: same with `implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2'` in app/bould.gradle

Comment: I edit my question with the dependencies

Comment: try adding implementation 'com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:1.2.16' to it

Comment: i already do that, but same error

Comment: with the fast info set one too? earlier it was jabx dependency

Comment: yes i put the two dependencies